# Explaination regarding bakctracking/recursive approach for combinations. Question regarding behaviour in recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, combinations, backtracking

The nums splice and temp pop operation runs twice after first return condition. Why? I have outputted everything in console.log to understand but could not get the reason why following is printed twice::

```
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
outside for loop::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
```

From what I understand it could do the operation once after return due to the return condition as the flow will go back to the line where the function was called.
Explanation regarding this would be really appreciated.

```js
const combination = (nums) => {
  let temp = []
  let result = []

  function backtracking(temp, nums) {
    console.log("temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
    if (nums.length === 0) {
      result.push([...temp])
      console.log("::::: result.push::  temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
      return
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      console.log("::temp.push::  i:: ", i, " temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
      temp.push(nums[i]);
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      console.log("before rec call:: i:: ", i, " temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
      backtracking(temp, nums);
      console.log("::new after rec call:: i:: ", i, " temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
      nums.splice(i, 0, temp.pop());
      console.log("after rec call:: temp:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
    }
    console.log("outside for loop:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
  }
  console.log("before calling bakctracking:: ", temp, " nums:: ", nums);
  backtracking(temp, nums)
  console.log(" result:: ", result);
}
combination([1, 2, 3]);
```

Follwing is the output for all console logs::

```
before calling bakctracking::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]  nums::  []//from this log --
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
outside for loop::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 2 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]              // --to this log
::temp.push::  i::  1  temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
temp::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 3, 2 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 1, 3, 2 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 1, 3, 2 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1, 3, 2 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
outside for loop::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 1, 3 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
outside for loop::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 1 ]  nums::  [ 2, 3 ]
after rec call:: temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  1  temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
temp::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 1, 3 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 2, 1, 3 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 2, 1, 3 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 1, 3 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
outside for loop::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 1 ]  nums::  [ 3 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  1  temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
temp::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 3, 1 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 2, 3, 1 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 2, 3, 1 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 2, 3, 1 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
outside for loop::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 2, 3 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
outside for loop::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 2 ]  nums::  [ 1, 3 ]
after rec call:: temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
::temp.push::  i::  2  temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
before rec call:: i::  2  temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
temp::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 1, 2 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 3, 1, 2 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 3, 1, 2 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 1, 2 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
outside for loop::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 1 ]  nums::  [ 2 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
::temp.push::  i::  1  temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
before rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
temp::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
::temp.push::  i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
before rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 2, 1 ]  nums::  []
temp::  [ 3, 2, 1 ]  nums::  []
::::: result.push::  temp::  [ 3, 2, 1 ]  nums::  []
::new after rec call:: i::  0  temp::  [ 3, 2, 1 ]  nums::  []
after rec call:: temp::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
outside for loop::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  1  temp::  [ 3, 2 ]  nums::  [ 1 ]
after rec call:: temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
outside for loop::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
::new after rec call:: i::  2  temp::  [ 3 ]  nums::  [ 1, 2 ]
after rec call:: temp::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
outside for loop::  []  nums::  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
result::  [
[ 1, 2, 3 ],
[ 1, 3, 2 ],
[ 2, 1, 3 ],
[ 2, 3, 1 ],
[ 3, 1, 2 ],
[ 3, 2, 1 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but simply a way to make it easier to see a cleaner log of what you're doing, tracking the recursive depth in the log statements, and simplifying the data logged.

Does this output make it any more clear?

```
before calling bakctracking - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     entering backtracking - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3],"depth":1}
     temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
         entering backtracking - {"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3],"depth":2}
         temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
         before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,2,3],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[1,2,3],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[1,2,3],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,2,3],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3]}
         new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,2],"nums":[3]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
         temp.push - {"i":1,"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
         before rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,3,2],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[1,3,2],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[1,3,2],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1,3,2],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2]}
         new after rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[1,3],"nums":[2]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
         outside for loop - {"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
     new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[1],"nums":[2,3]}
     after rec call - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     temp.push - {"i":1,"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     before rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
         entering backtracking - {"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3],"depth":2}
         temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
         before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,1,3],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[2,1,3],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[2,1,3],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,1,3],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3]}
         new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,1],"nums":[3]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
         temp.push - {"i":1,"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
         before rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,3,1],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[2,3,1],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[2,3,1],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[2,3,1],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1]}
         new after rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[2,3],"nums":[1]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
         outside for loop - {"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
     new after rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[2],"nums":[1,3]}
     after rec call - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     temp.push - {"i":2,"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     before rec call - {"i":2,"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
         entering backtracking - {"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2],"depth":2}
         temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
         before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,1,2],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[3,1,2],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[3,1,2],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,1,2],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2]}
         new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,1],"nums":[2]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
         temp.push - {"i":1,"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
         before rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1]}
             entering backtracking - {"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1],"depth":3}
             temp.push - {"i":0,"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1]}
             before rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,2,1],"nums":[]}
                 entering backtracking - {"temp":[3,2,1],"nums":[],"depth":4}
                 result.push - {"temp":[3,2,1],"nums":[]}
             new after rec call - {"i":0,"temp":[3,2,1],"nums":[]}
             after rec call - {"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1]}
             outside for loop - {"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1]}
         new after rec call - {"i":1,"temp":[3,2],"nums":[1]}
         after rec call - {"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
         outside for loop - {"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
     new after rec call - {"i":2,"temp":[3],"nums":[1,2]}
     after rec call - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
     outside for loop - {"temp":[],"nums":[1,2,3]}
 result - [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

You can see the minor tweaks I made to your logging to achieve this by expanding this snippet:

```js
const {log, display} = ((lines = []) => ({
  log: (depth) => (msg, obj) => lines .push (`${'    ' .repeat (depth)} ${msg} - ${JSON .stringify (obj)}`),
  display: () => console .log (lines .join('\n'))
}))() 

const combination = (nums) => {
  let temp = []
  let result = []

  function backtracking(temp, nums, depth) {
    log (depth) ("entering backtracking", {temp, nums, depth});
    if (nums.length === 0) {
      result.push([...temp])
      log (depth) ("result.push", {temp, nums});
      return
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      log (depth) ("temp.push", {i, temp, nums});
      temp.push(nums[i]);
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      log (depth) ("before rec call", {i, temp, nums});
      backtracking(temp, nums, depth + 1);
      log (depth) ("new after rec call", {i, temp, nums});
      nums.splice(i, 0, temp.pop());
      log (depth) ("after rec call", {temp, nums});
    }
    log (depth) ("outside for loop", {temp, nums});
  }
  log (0) ("before calling bakctracking", {temp, nums});
  backtracking(temp, nums, 1)
  log (0) ("result", result);
}

combination ([1, 2, 3]);

display ()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: thanks for that. But still i'm not able to understand after the temp array is added to result when nums length has become zero, the pop operation on temp array is done when flow returns to backtracking function call. Then again the flow goes to line after backtracking method call in for loop. But I do not understand why? the pop operation  on temp happens twice after the length of num array becomes zero, its not clear to me why does that happen. If u have clarification around that then surely it will be helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't have the time to try to understand this.  I would find it much easier to understand with immutable structures.  Have you tried a debugger for the case `[1, 2]`?  that should be small enough to understand and be able to step through.